# Искажение фона внутри прозрачного текста

Tags: вёрстка, дизайн

Получил заказ на создание анимированного слайдера, оплата была какая-то подозрительно большая и я быстро за него взялся, и внезапно встал в тупик.
Заказчик требует 100%-ого совпадение с psd-макетом. Проблема вот в чём, имеется текстовый прозрачный логотип MCbrothers. Однако фон слова МС - преломляет изображение за ним(чем-то похоже на преломление света в воде).
Я не представляю как это можно реализовать и с помощью чего.
Картинка - скрин части PSD макета с этим логотипом, в этой части хорошо видно как преломляется изображение на примере двух "выходов".

[image: Часть макета]

Comment: А если заказчик будет потом проверять верстку в IE6?

Comment: А есть предложение как это кроссбраузерно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поэкспериментировать с одним из css-свойств filter. Но там все равно будет ограниченная поддержка, т.к. на большинстве старых браузеров работать не будет.

Можно попробовать использовать фильтр blur (но это будет не совсем преломление, скорее его имитация), либо matrix. Также можно использовать фильтр со смещением изображения-маски на несколько пикселей в сторону (но опять же, это будет имитация преломления).

В вашем случае скорее всего в Photoshop использовали масштабирование маски, поэтому можно также ограничиться свойствами смещения/масштаба (будет 100% совпадение, если точно подогнать).

Comment: Можно поподробнее о свойствах смещения/масштаба?
А то я совсем не представляю, так как в отличие от psd-макета это отдельный элемент с текстом то фильтры работают не так(пробовал blur, совсем не то получается)

Comment: во-первых, требуется сделать маску, на которой и будет висеть прозрачный текст (почитать можно здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/164409/), во-вторых, к маскируемому слою применяем эффекты (можно через filter, можно через transform - если ограничиваемся масштабом и смещением).

Comment: по маскам можно еще здесь посмотреть https://htmlhook.ru/css-masking.html

Comment: да, заметил, что само изображение на водяном знаке более темное, в сравнении с базовым. соответственно, потребуется его либо затемнить через filter, либо изменить яркость в фотошопе (если в слайдере изображения не будут подзагружаться динамически).

Comment: советую сделать маску на основе png и попробовать добиться нужного эффекта преломления с помощью transform. так будет максимальная кроссбраузерная совместимость.